# Repair mssqlsystemresource.ldf

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I accidently deleted mssqlsystemresource.mdf and mssqlsystemresource.ldf.

I undeleted them both, but the .ldf file is corrupted (bad FGID), and because of this I can no longer start up my database instance.

There have never been any backups of the system databases.  I have a database with a ton of data on it within this instance.  I do have a week old  backup of that data, but would rather not restore it.

Any advice on how to quickly get my instance up and running again?

Comment: This is probably not ideal, but I copied the model and resource mdf and ldf files from another machine which had the same installer run on it and thing 'seem' to be working properly

Comment: Copying the resource DB (MDF+LDF) from the distribution media (the CD) should work, as well as copying it from an identical installation (same version).

Comment: If you can't get your instance back up then you can always reattach your database to a new instance using the data and log files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely copy the LDF from a different installation, just put it in the right directory and the SQL service should start up just fine. You shouldn't run into any problems as long as you copy it over from a similar enough installation. It looks like you already tried this based on one of your comments. You can just take this as reassurance that you did it the right way.